# How to move from fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to jump from one fragment to another fragment using "main" as my container, but I keep getting the "unfortunately Application has stopped" error message. Here's the code:

```
package com.wiss.clic.clickit;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {




    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



    }
    public void Click(View v){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, new GameFragment()).commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: post logcat here to better help

Comment: Please post the full stack trace or the error message you're getting

Answer (score 0):

**Use getSupportFragmentManager() instead getFragmentManager() because ur extending
[import android.support.v4.app.Fragment]  support-v4 not [import android.app.Fragment;]**

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, new GameFragment()).commit();

**else replace package name from import android.support.v4.app.Fragment to import android.app.Fragment;**